# SpringBoot Microservice with GraalVM Native Image without Spring Native Beta

Tags: spring-boot, quarkus, graalvm, helidon, spring-native

I am exploring a possibilty to convert my existing Spring Boot facade services to be compatible with GraalVM image. I have tried to do a PoC with Spring Native (0.11). And it actually serves the purpose (solving cold-start problem). But I am skeptical to go with Spring Native in production as it's still with Beta. I am evaluating my option with Helidon & Quarkus and the performance benchmark seems to be fascinating.But as we have 100+ Microservices to convert and it will be a huge manual effort and we don't want that right now.

Is there any other option available with Spring Boot with GraalVM native image but without Spring Native Beta.My requirement is pretty simple. We are using few flavors of Spring (boot-starter, WebServiceTemplate, Spring Cloud for config server & discovery , zpipkin for logging). If I don't want to use Spring Boot what are the other stable options available within Java EE without introducing a new framework (aka Helidon or Quarkus).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doubt is not on code perspective rather a view, that we need from community.

Comment: FYI: Helidon has full CDI support in Native image.